# Dynamic or parameter callback URL for Facebook OAuth?

Tags: facebook, oauth

Is there a way to specify a dynamic callback url for the redirect from Facebook authorization? Facebook app is requiring to enter a url with a slash at the end. What I am trying to do is to do is add a username or the app key so I can do some dynamic logic on the callback url page. I would like to use the same callback url for many users, so even parameters would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know you can not append parameters like you want.

But in some cases parameters get appended by facebook (e.g. auth_token in OAuth).